# Powering a system using batteries

Tags: arduino-nano, power, battery

I made an arduino nano IR sensor based auto liquid dispenser. Currently it is being powered by a 12V 2 amps adapter. The 12v adapter is connected to a LM2596 DC to DC buck converter which converts the 12V to 5V and powers the arduino, IR sensor and a regular green LED. Also I am using a RO valve solenoid (rated upto 24V DC) which is being powered by the 12V adapter. So whenever the IR sensor is triggered, the DC motor (5V 200mA) and solenoid (12V 300-500mA) are turned on for 3 seconds.

Now, I intend to power this system via batteries. I am considering the following 3 options.

a.) Lithium batteries in series (4 of 3.7V batteries). But again here I believe things would be complex as I have to make a BMS and charger for this. Is anything available off the shelf so that I can directly integrate the battery and charger with my existing system ?

b.) Connect 8 AAA batteries in series to get 12V. But how long would these batteries last for my application ?

c.) Connect 2 9V batteries in series. Again, can you guys please tell me how long these may last in the system.

Arduino nano I believe consumes 20mA and the IR sensor probably around another 10- 20mA.
If it wasnt for the solenoid, I was considering connecting a mobile power bank to power the system.

Comment: You should check out radio controlled model suppliers. They have the best offerings for batteries and chargers.

Comment: The 9V block batteries are out here. They cannot provide enough current to power the solenoid

Comment: Using AA would give you about 5 days of runtime, assuming it's activated once an hour (24 times a day) and the LM2596 running at 80% efficiency. With AAA you'd only get 2.5 days. Most of the power is used by the Arduino + IR sensor. So putting the Arduino in sleep mode most of the time, would give you a lot longer runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go with 3 lithium batteries in series and for proper balance charging of batteries, you can use an off the shell 3s lithium charging circuit like this [here](https://robu.in/product/3s-12v-18650-lithium-battery-protection-board-12v-10a-overcharge-overcurrent-protection/?gclid=CjwKCAjwlZf3BRABEiwA8Q0qq9as1ergawrXgdhpC2R4g2RkCU830LG1Fb6Cxtejf4sBEsifmbmioxoCZfIQAvD_BwE).So you will get 4.2*3 = 12.6V on full charge and on full discharge you will get 3.7*3=11.1v out of the battery.

So still I think your pump motor would work on 11v and ther are chances that your solanoid also work on 11v it will just draw more current then usual.

Comment: Thank you. As per datasheet (https://aws.robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/DATASHEET_ROBU.IN_.pdf), I believe I need to connect 3S1P to get 12.6V. Also, can I charge the batteries simultaneously with a 12V 2A adapter while powering the load ? Also, how do I know when I should connect the charger? How long would my system last with 3s1p combination of 3 18650 batteries.

Comment: You should not run a device from batteries whilst at the same time charging the batteries. The charger will have a hard job knowing when the batteries are charged (dv/dt won't work right) and you risk overcharging.  For 3S batteries you need a balancing charger otherwise you can end up with a reverse charged cell as the cells discharge unevenly. That will kill your battery. You need an intelligent "In-place" charger that disconnects the battery while it's being charged and powers the device directly from the incoming power.

Comment: @Majenko As per the datasheet page 3 (https://aws.robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/DATASHEET_ROBU.IN_.pdf), I believe this has the power multiplexing mechanism in place as they have connected charger supply and load together.

Comment: Looks good to me, though that's not a charger, just protection. It should protect the batteries from over/under charge with a dumb charger, which is good.

Comment: @Majenko thank you. But still this doesnt have the auto disconnect from the battery and power the load directly when the dumb adapter is connected , right ? So simultaneously connecting adapter to power the load and charge batteries would not be possible.

Comment: The protection circuit will disconnect the battery when it's charged.

Comment: @user3796354  It will not make any issue if you charge under load condition because your load will get its power from the battery as well as the adapter so no worry.
but for charging voltage it will not charge fully if you give 12v it will make battery voltage level to 12v but not more than that so you need to provide more than 12.6v to 13v as per the datasheet.
And for time calculation that how long your battery last you can use online converters like [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-battery-life)

Comment: @dharmik Thanks. Instead I can also use a battery pack like this one (https://robokits.co.in/batteries-chargers/skycell-li-ion-battery/11.1v-skycell-li-ion-batteries/li-ion-11.1v-2200mah-2c-with-inbuilt-charger-protection), right ? It has built in BMS and can be charged from a 12V 1A adapter.

Comment: @user3796354 yes you can because this battery pack has the same circuit inside.

Comment: Dharmik, Do you think the battery in the link above can be charged with a regular charger ? Because I was researching about charging lithium batteries and I believe the charger should be able to maintain absolute max @4.2v per cell which regular chargers wont be able to do.

Comment: @user3796354 It will charge your battery pack with 12v regular but not full charge because the voltage has a property of flowing from high potential to low potential voltage so it will do charge to the max voltage of 12v not more than that until you give more voltage to it. So you can do one thing if you want full charge battery and regular adapter you can add an 2amp DC-DC bust converter in betwen for changing 12v to around 12.6 to 13v.

Comment: @dharmik ok. thanks

Comment: That is not a charger; it is a protection circuit aka BMS. Try getting a 3S balancing BMS for building your battery pack and use a proper charger to charge the pack.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a 12V sealed cell lead-acid battery. Those are fairly cheap and easy to find in a wide variety of capacities, and chargers are also simple and easy to find.

A car battery would power your system approximately forever, since they have such huge capacity.

Figuring out how long a given type of battery will last is a simple question of math. Figure out the average current draw of your entire project, in milliamps. (You need to include the power consumed by your voltage regulator. The linear regulators built into Arduinos are quite inefficient, and work by dissipating excess voltage as heat.)

The total power of a battery is expressed in milliamp/hours. (where 1 milliamp/hour is a milliamp of power drawn for a full hour.) If you your system draws 2 amps, or 2000 milliamps average current, and your battery is rated for 2000 mAh, or 2 amp/hours, the battery will last 1 hour.

For battery-powered systems you should think about skipping the built-in linear regulator in your Arduino and instead using a switching regulator and providing regulated 5V directly to the board. Switching regulators can run at 90%+ efficiency, compared to something like 40% - 50% efficiency for linear regulators (I don't have a specific efficiency figure for linear regulators on hand, and it depends on input voltage compared to output voltage. The 40% - 50% number is an educated guess.)